# WordPress Website Not Correctly Pointing to Domain Name (GoDaddy)

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, web-hosting

I have a Hosting Plan with GoDaddy and also purchased a domain name from them.

http://sittananetworkmarketing.com/

It was working fine, But don't know for some reasons it's not working. When I enter the above URL, I get

**This sittananetworkmarketing.com page can’t be found
No webpage was found for the web address: http://sittananetworkmarketing.com/
HTTP ERROR 404**

[Error being thrown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zgyc8.png)

and the same error is shown for wp-admin.

However, I can clearly see my website in the File Manager - public html (Backend of GoDaddy CPanel), like

[Public Html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiziI.png)

I have contacted GoDaddy Support, But they are saying that this website is not hosted with GoDaddy. Don't know why they are saying it, because everything is with GoDaddy. They are not helping me :(

[Hosting Checker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0I2c.png)

I would appreciate any help and guidance:) Thank You!

Kind Regards

Comment: Did they say who is hosting the website, if not them?

Comment: No, they say they are unable to track the website :(